# Unified local app storage across platforms including deployment and dev-testing

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-phone, isolatedstorage, portable-class-library

Although I have experience in C#, I am only just now starting to explore developing under Windows 8, Windows Phone, and Xamarin.

I am attempting to write a Portable Class Library which will run on Ios, Android, Windows Phone, and Windows 7 and up.

Early in my project, while attempting to set up some basic unit tests, I bumped up against IsolatedStorage.  Okay, I can store my files in IsolatedStorage.  But Windows 7 and 8 do not have this class (that I can see).  (Because of this obstacle I temporarily switched to a dll.  I will go back to a pcl once I get these questions answered.)

So now I want to abstract the file system such that when I target different targets, it uses IsolatedStorage when it should and the Windows file system when it should.

Also, regarding unit testing (which I do in Debug Configuration), I could put the directory anywhere, so I could just choose, Directory.GetCurrent() I suppose.  But I don't want to suppose.

**Now for my questions:**  (There are two)

What is the recommended approach to handle this -- getting a single root directory for application data that works for all targets?

I want to have some files for testing which are persisted in a subdirecory of my solution directory.  In my abstracting class (not abstract class, but file-system-abstracting class), should I have code like this:?

```
AbstractedFileSystem abstractRootPath;
#if DEBUG
   String abstractRootPathString = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
   abstractRootPath = AbstractedFileSystem.CreateFromString(abstractRootPathString);
#else
   abstractRootPath = AbstractedFileSystem.CreateFromIsolatedStorage();
#endif
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to store? If it's mere text (or any derived form of text), you can think about setting up some small database, and add a Data Access Layer inside your project, that gets used by all platforms.

Comment: Yes, it is mostly text.  But a local database seems too thick for this small amount of data that would be.  It just seems to me there would be an established pattern to abstract it such that it works in both File and IsolatedStorage.  Does Windows 8 have IsolatedStorage?  Can I control it to be in a certain directory for my unit tests to be persisted in source control?

Comment: I think you're clinging too much to your IsolatedStorage. Setting up a database on a server (not locally) to be used by all your applications is a great way to reduce file size of the app, get great reusability and a lot of scalability.

Comment: You may be right, but since this question received a Tumbleweed medal, and I still have no direct answers, I am thinking I will have to figure it out without any community help.  (Magicbjørn, please don't take my tone as hostile towards you.  I don't feel hostility.  I'm just surprised there is not already an established pattern for something as simple as testing this that does not involve operating a database.)